# Boostrap 4 Navbar with search input/icon placement (absolute position) not working when I change max-height and overflow-y

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, css-position, navbar

I am trying to make a search input with an embedded search icon work in Bootstrap 4 navbar when the mobile menu is displayed.  Below is my Boostrap 3 version that worked pretty easily...

[image]

I have a very long 'mobile' menu due to the nature of the application so I want to apply a max-height and overflow-y to the navbar-collapse so it doesn't cover entire screen.

However, when I apply those styles in Boostrap 4, my search icon does not stay 'inside' the input:

[image]

The styles I have applied to my search inputs are:

```
<div class="has-search">
    <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback execute-quick-search"></span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control quick-search" placeholder="Quick Search">
</div>

.has-search .form-control {
  padding-right: 2.375rem;
}

.has-search .form-control-feedback {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  width: 2.375rem;
  height: 2.375rem;
  line-height: 2.375rem;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 1.1875rem;
}
```

I am able to make the search icon stay inside the input if I apply max-height/overflow-y styles to the entire `.navbar` element.  But this is not the look I am going for, and worse, it allows the mobile togglerButton to be scrolled off the screen.  I have made a fiddle that reproduces the error.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oz6m04v5/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `has-search`. Also apply `max-height` etc to `navbar-collapse` only in *mobile view*.

See demo below:

```css
.has-search { /* ADDED */
  position: relative;
}

.has-search .form-control {
  padding-right: 2.375rem;
}

.has-search .form-control-feedback {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  display: block;
  width: 2.375rem;
  height: 2.375rem;
  line-height: 2.375rem;
  text-align: center;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  right: 1.1875rem;
}
@media (max-width: 991px) { /* ADDED */
  .navbar-collapse {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Dropdown
            </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="has-search">
      <span class="fa fa-search form-control-feedback execute-quick-search"></span>
      <input type="text" class="form-control quick-search" placeholder="Quick Search">
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>
```

Comment: Question, isn't using an `input-group` better to get the look of the input field with the icon?

Comment: I want the search icon to look like it appears 'inside' the input box, not the standard 'gray' appended icon.  That is how I understood `'input-group` to work.